# Self-adjoint operators on $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, linear-algebra

I want to show that self-adjoint operators in a complex space of dimensions 2 does form a real vector space.
It seems a very simple questions, but then I realize that I am not sure of how to represent these self-adjoint operators. So my question is: from where I start?

My first look whenwriting the answer was to start from the defition of a self-adjoint operator:

```
<Av , w > = <v , Aw >
```

where A is a self-adjoint operator, and v and w are vectors in C². But I am not sure if this is enough, because there is nothing there that refers specifically to C². Thus, I do not know where to start.

Comment: It's good that the definition doesn't make any reference to $\mathbb{C}^2$, because the result is true for self-adjoint operators on any vector space.

Comment: yeah, you are right. Guess I got too attached to C² when I read the exercise. But now, it is very clear. Thank you :ppp

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is any self adjoint operataor and $B$ any other  self adjoint opertor, what  conditions on $\lambda$ and $\mu$  make $\lambda A+\mu B$ a self adjoint?